# Как сделать обновление программы?

Tags: python

Не могу придумать, как можно реализовать обновление своей программы. Есть результат в виде exe (Pyinstaller), допустим, при запуске сверяется с базой на наличие новой версии. Если версия появилась, то скачивает ее, а дальше не знаю, как реализовать. Нужно, чтоб старый файл (exe) переписался новым, но программа ведь уже запущена и переписать себя уже не дает.

Comment: Винды загружать лениво, поэтому проверить не могу. Попробуйте старый exe-шник переименовать (а после перезапуска -- всё равно ведь придётся -- удалить)

Answer (score 6):

Использовать отдельную программу для обновления?

Главная программа проверяет наличие обновлений, запрашивает разрешение на обновление, запускает программу обновления и закрывается (сохраняя при необходимости рабочие данные).

Ну а программа обновления уже делает свое грязное дело, и при удачном обновлении запускает основную программу (возможно, с флагом, указывающим на необходимость восстановления предыдущего состояния). После чего самовыпиливается, опять же.

Ну или вариант попроще - все обновления только через специальную утилиту.

Comment: Смотрите в сторону модуля subproccess